# Isomorphism $\{1\}\times \mathbb C^*\to \{1\}\times \mathbb C^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism, linear-groups

I am reading a text where I have trouble understanding an argument:

Let $f: \mathbb C^*\times \mathbb C^*\to \mathbb C^*\times \mathbb C^*$ an isomorphism, such that $f(\{1\}\times \mathbb C^*)= \{1\}\times \mathbb C^*$.
Further, let $|x|\neq 1$.

The following argument is made:
$f_{\{1\}\times \mathbb C^*}: \{1\}\times \mathbb C^*\to \{1\}\times \mathbb C^*$ is an isomorphism of linear groups. Therefore $f(1,|x|^2)\in \{(1,|x|^2),(1,|x|^{-2}\}$.

---

Why should this follow? As far as I see it, the condition $f(\{1\}\times \mathbb C^*)= \{1\}\times \mathbb C^*$ means that $f_{\{1\}\times \mathbb C^*}$ comes from an isomorphism $\mathbb C^* \to \mathbb C^*$. But these could map $|x|^2$ to any value. For example the homomorphism could be a rotation.

Comment: A rotation is not an endomorphism (homomorphism from a group to itself) of the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers. Consider that $1$ has to map to $1$, for instance.

Comment: @Arthur: Oh, you are right. But what about $z\mapsto z^k$? If $|k|\neq 1$, then stil the claim in the question does not hold?

Comment: ah...nevermind, if $|k|\neq 1$, then the homomorphism is not injective. But how can I be sure that there is no other possibility?